# Mongodb $unwind aggregation not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb aggregation. my mongo document have many arrays. I need to export it as a flat file. For that I need structure it. I tried following aggregation:

```
[
{$unwind : "$items" },
{$unwind : "$items.discounts"},    
{$unwind : "$payments"},
{$unwind : "$payments.items"},  
{$unwind : "$payments.refunds"}
]
```

It worked, then i just added following condition to filter data

```
[
{$match : { "updatedtime": { $gt: 1514764800000}}},
{$unwind : "$items" },
{$unwind : "$items.discounts"},    
{$unwind : "$payments"},
{$unwind : "$payments.items"},  
{$unwind : "$payments.refunds"}
]
```

returns 0 rows, I tried again with match statement alone

```
[
{$match : { "updatedtime": { $gt: 1514764800000}}}
]
```

It Works again.

```
[
{$match : { "updatedtime": { $gt: 1514764800000}}},
{$unwind : "$items" }
]
```

Works.

```
[
{$match : { "updatedtime": { $gt: 1514764800000}}},
{$unwind : "$items" },
{$unwind : "$items.discounts"}
]
```

Not working. Can any one tell me is am doing something wrong. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This will happen if `items.discounts` is an empty array for the filtered documents. Is that a possibility?

Comment: It is possible. My doubt is whether the unwind aggregation fails if the specific field is empty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) an array field like `items.discounts` that's empty, the resulting output is no documents. To preserve these documents, enable the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option of `$unwind`:

```
[
{$match : { "updatedtime": { $gt: 1514764800000}}},
{$unwind : "$items" },
{$unwind : {path: "$items.discounts", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}}
]
```